# Update with remove and create entity property collection using Entity Framework Core in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a models that looks like:

```
public class Rack
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RackRow { get; set; }
    public int RackSize { get; set; }
    public int SystemId { get; set; }
    public System System { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte ModuleSlot { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int RackId { get; set; }
    public Rack Rack { get; set; }
}
```

Those are connected by realtions in fluentAPI like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.Module>().HasOne(entity => entity.Rack).WithMany(entity => entity.Modules).HasForeignKey(entity => entity.RackId);
```

Now I have this simple Update command in WebApi:

```
    [HttpPut("systemId"), ActionName("UpdateRack")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateRack([FromBody]DTO.Rack requestInput, int systemId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (systemId == 0 || !requestInput.Id.HasValue) return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
            var systemEntity = await this.systemService.GetSystem(systemId);
            if (systemEntity == null) return NotFound();

            systemEntity.Racks = this.mapper.Map(new List<DTO.Rack>{requestInput}, systemEntity.Racks);

            return Ok(await this.systemService.Update(systemEntity));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Now this works, but i when I remove or add something to Modules collection it is not processed, so my question is, does entity framework core is capable of adding or removing records in update enity collection operation?

Comment: It's hard to answer because the code for `this.sytemService.Update` is missing. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) article describes how to update related data.

Comment: Also, please provide the code, how you tried to remove/add items.

Comment: If an entity is retrieved by the Ef Core context, then it is tracked by default which means that your changes will be automatically saved the next time you call `yourContext.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core still can do it.

My entity has total 2 before update first record and create new record.

After updating and creating new, total 3 and first record is updated.

[image]